# How to get count rows in AspxGridView?

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a Gridview.I want to get count of Status=1 and Status=0 rows

```
    Id    Bla    Bla     Bla  Status

    1                         1 
    27                        0
    323                       1

<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="grid" Width="100%" >
            <Columns>

         some colums

         ...

         ...

</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Status" FieldName="Online">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>    
        </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

How can I get counts ?

I want to display like this

```
  lblOnline.Text="Online Dealers : "+  countOnline.ToString();
  lblOffline.Text="Offline Dealers : "+ countOffline.ToString();
```

Comment: Use the datasource that you are binding to this gridview to achieve what you require.

Comment: Is there any way get from Gridview ?

Comment: you should loop through the gridview and perform your operation

Comment: declare two variables;
for loop for the gridviewrow count;
fetching the status and iterating the variable value to =1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int countOnline = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if (dr["Status"].Equals("1"))
    {
          countOnline++;
    }
}
int countOffline = dataTable.Rows.Count - countOnline;
```

You may also extract the Status column to an ArrayList and sort the list using ArrayList.Sort and count only the first sorted 0 values.

Comment: The result of countOnline is 0.

Comment: You might change dr["Status"].Equals("1") condition according to your data type, or change the condition to dr["Status"].ToString().Equals("1")

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)

{
  int status = Convert.toInt32(row.Cells['statuscolumnindex'].Text);
    if(status == 1)
      { countA++; }
    else
      { countB++; }
}
```

Here statuscolumnindex is the integer index of you Status column in the GridView. e.g. (row.Cells[2]) .Just the integer value. This is not the exact code, you will have to make it as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can display number of all rows.I want to display counts of Status=1 and Status=0

Comment: For doing that, you will have to loop over all the rows of the GridView and set two counter variables for each Status and keep incrementing them according to the Status value that you get in each GridViewRow.

Comment: See my above edited answer. Maybe this gets you what you need.